# Remove Values of Data Frame based on Other Column Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, conditional-statements

I want to delete cell values from a particular column of a data frame based on the values in another column.

For every row that contains "TRUE" in column 'match', the value in column 'Total Difference by Brand' should be deleted (not zero, just empty).

| variable | Difference Magnitude | Total Difference by Brand | Total Difference by Location | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total New Funding Sources | 1406904 | 5031189 | 4373182 | FALSE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 75821 | 5031189 | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 33692 | 5031189 | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 2627094 | 5031189 | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 400000 | 500000 | 4373182 | FALSE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 500000 | 500000 | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 1406904 | 5131189 | 4373182 | FALSE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 75821 | 5131189 | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 33692 | 5131189 | 4373182 | TRUE |

Data Frame should look like this:

| variable | Difference Magnitude | Total Difference by Brand | Total Difference by Location | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total New Funding Sources | 1406904 | 5031189 | 4373182 | FALSE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 75821 |  | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 33692 |  | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 2627094 |  | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 400000 | 500000 | 4373182 | FALSE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 500000 |  | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 1406904 | 5131189 | 4373182 | FALSE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 75821 |  | 4373182 | TRUE |
| Total New Funding Sources | 33692 |  | 4373182 | TRUE |

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "variable": {
            0: "Total New Funding Sources",
            1: "Total New Funding Sources",
            2: "Total New Funding Sources",
            3: "Total New Funding Sources",
        },
        "Difference Magnitude": {0: 1406904.0, 1: 75821.0, 2: 33692.0, 3: 2627094.0},
        "Total Difference by Brand": {
            0: 5031189.0,
            1: 5031189.0,
            2: 5031189.0,
            3: 5031189.0,
        },
        "Total Difference by Location": {
            0: 4373182.0,
            1: 4373182.0,
            2: 4373182.0,
            3: 4373182.0,
        },
        "match": {0: False, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True},
    }
)

df.loc[df["match"].eq(True), "Total Difference by Brand"] = ""

print(df[["variable", "Total Difference by Brand"]])
# Outputs
                    variable Total Difference by Brand
0  Total New Funding Sources                 5031189.0
1  Total New Funding Sources
2  Total New Funding Sources
3  Total New Funding Sources
```

Comment: That does not work, unfortunately. It did not change the values in the data set for me

Comment: Most probably because of your dataframe dtypes, which must be different from the ones in my example. Could you post the output of `df.head(9).to_dict()`?

Comment: 'variable': {0: 'Total New Funding Sources',
  1: 'Total New Funding Sources',
  2: 'Total New Funding Sources',
  3: 'Total New Funding Sources'},
 'Difference Magnitude': {0: 1406904.0, 1: 75821.0, 2: 33692.0, 3: 2627094.0},
 'Total Difference by Brand': {0: 5031189.0,
  1: 5031189.0,
  2: 5031189.0,
  3: 5031189.0},
 'Total Difference by Location': {0: 4373182.0,
  1: 4373182.0,
  2: 4373182.0,
  3: 4373182.0},
 'match': {0: False, 1: True, 2: True, 3: True}}       I did the first four lines because 9 lines was too many to fit into the comment field

Comment: And the dtypes: 
**variable**                               object,

**Difference Magnitude**                  float64,

**Total Difference by Brand**            object,
**Total Difference by Location**    float64,
**match**                                    bool.

Comment: Ok, so you have bool values  (`True`) instead of string values (`TRUE`), as your question could let one think. See my updated answer, which works fine with the data you provided.